# Breadth First Search: Can't find path, shortest path to border in 2D-Array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I try programming a "Circle the dot" game. The basic game idea is that you have to surround the blue dot before it escapes. With every placed obstacle (orange colored dot), the blue dot ("player") moves one step to the border. If you haven't circled the blue dot until he's on the border, you lost and the game restarts.

Therefor I have to do a ***Breath First Search over a 2D-Array of UIButtons*** to find the shortest path from the playerButton to the border.

**The problem:**

It often doesn't find a path to the border (prints "No path found!" in the console and restarts) EVEN THOUGH there is a possible path for the blue dot to the border/ the dot isn't circled by orange dots. It also doesn't go the shortest path, sometimes the dot just loops up. down, up, down,... which makes it pretty easy to win.

**My project:**

The best thing would be if you can just [**download my project**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtl410wzrg3elwg/dot%202%202.zip?dl=0) (all together 300 lines of code) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtl410wzrg3elwg/dot%202%202.zip?dl=0).Then you can test the problem with those patterns: (click in the given sequence on the labeled buttons/ dots)

1. Finds no possible path, but there are many: (1,2) -> (0,3) -> (1,4)
2. Finds no possible path, but there is one: (2,2) -> (1,3) -> (2,4) -> (2,5) -> (3,5) -> (4,4) -> (3,3)
3. Loops Up/Down/Up/...: (3,4) -> (2,3) -> (2,2) -> (1,1) -> (1,0) -> (3,4) -> (3,5) -> (4,6) -> (4,7) -> (5,8)

Important: There are infinite possible ways to see those problems, the 3 patterns are only to find the problem quicker and you don't have to play it multiple times until an issue appears. ALSO, you have to let line 94 (`possibleNeighbours.shuffle()`) uncommented, as this would randomize the patterns.

If you don't want to download my whole project you can take a look at my breadth-first-search method, which return the next x and y coordinates the blue dot has to move to:

```
    func findDirection()->String{
    var blockedArr:  [[Bool]] = [[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                 [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]] // Can do it like this as its always 9X9
    
    for btnline in btnArr{ //Block all dots which are already occupied
        for btn in btnline{
            if(btn.backgroundColor != defaultColor){
                blockedArr[getX(btn: btn)][getY(btn: btn)] = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    let otheryQueue = otherQueue<Pair>()
    let pair = Pair()
    var possibleNeighbours = findPossibleNeighbours(btn: btnArr[playerX][playerY], blockedArr: blockedArr) //returns array of all possible neighbours of given dot
    print(String(possibleNeighbours.description) + " possibeNeighs beginning" )
   //possibleNeighbours.shuffle() //IMPORTANT: Uncomment this to make it more random
    
    for neighbour in possibleNeighbours{
        if(isOnBorder(point: neighbour)){
            print("Blue dot is on border")
            return neighbour
        }
        pair.setPair(firstValue: neighbour, secondValue: neighbour)
        otheryQueue.enqueue(key: pair)
        blockedArr[getXFromString(string: neighbour)][getYFromString(string: neighbour)] = true
    }
    
    // Start the search
    while(!otheryQueue.isEmpty){
        let pointPair = otheryQueue.dequeue()
        let button = btnArr[getXFromString(string: (pointPair?.getFirst())!)][getYFromString(string: (pointPair?.getFirst())!)]
        possibleNeighbours = findPossibleNeighbours(btn: button, blockedArr: blockedArr)
        for neighbour in possibleNeighbours{
            if isOnBorder(point: neighbour){
                return (pointPair?.getSecond())!
            }
            pair.setPair(firstValue: neighbour, secondValue: (pointPair?.getSecond())!)
            otheryQueue.enqueue(key: pair)
            blockedArr[getXFromString(string: neighbour)][getYFromString(string: neighbour)] = true
        }
    }
    print("No path found!")
    return "-1 -1" //return (-1, -1) position if NO PATH FOUND
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the game view, to help understand what I mean with (1,2), (0,3), blue dot and so on:

[image: Screenshot]

If there are questions please ask.

Thanks for any help!!

SwiftHobby

Comment: At least part of the current problem is that you're using only one instance of the `Pair` object and changing its value rather than creating new objects to enqueue each time.  Since your queue only holds references, that means its existing data was being changed.  Insert `let pair = Pair()` before each call to `setPair` instead of doing it only once for the whole function.  (Note that I discovered this by printing which button was being checked in your `while` loop and seeing duplicates.)

Comment: Ohhhhh yesssss! I cannot thank you enough Phillip, that was the problem, my god!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this block of code inside your `findDirection()` func:

```
    let otheryQueue = otherQueue<Pair>()
    let pair = Pair()
    var possibleNeighbours = findPossibleNeighbours(btn: btnArr[playerX][playerY], blockedArr: blockedArr) //returns array of all possible neighbours of given dot
    print(String(possibleNeighbours.description) + " possibeNeighs beginning" )
   //possibleNeighbours.shuffle() //IMPORTANT: Uncomment this to make it more random
    
    for neighbour in possibleNeighbours{
        if(isOnBorder(point: neighbour)){
            print("Blue dot is on border")
            return neighbour
        }
        pair.setPair(firstValue: neighbour, secondValue: neighbour)
        otheryQueue.enqueue(key: pair)
        blockedArr[getXFromString(string: neighbour)][getYFromString(string: neighbour)] = true
    }

    // Start the search
    while(!otheryQueue.isEmpty){
       ...
```

To debug, I added this immediately before the "Start the search":

```
    var p = otheryQueue.first
    while p != nil {
        print("first", p?.data.first, "second", p?.data.second)
        p = p?.next
    }
    
    // Start the search
    while(!otheryQueue.isEmpty){
       ...
```

If I start by tapping on any gray dot, such as `0 0`, the output I get in console is:

```
Button 0 0 tapped
["4 3", "5 4", "4 5", "3 5", "3 4", "3 3"] possibeNeighs beginning
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
```

(if I tap first on `3 3` the output will be all "3 4").

Your code is creating only one `pair` object, and then modifying its values each time through the loop.

You probably want to create a ***new*** `pair` object each time you want to `.enqueue` it:

```
    for neighbour in possibleNeighbours{
        if(isOnBorder(point: neighbour)){
            print("Blue dot is on border")
            return neighbour
        }
        
        // add this line
        let pair = Pair()
        
        pair.setPair(firstValue: neighbour, secondValue: neighbour)
        otheryQueue.enqueue(key: pair)
        blockedArr[getXFromString(string: neighbour)][getYFromString(string: neighbour)] = true
    }
```

Now my console output when first tapping on `0 0` is:

```
Button 0 0 tapped
["4 3", "5 4", "4 5", "3 5", "3 4", "3 3"] possibeNeighs beginning
first Optional("4 3") second Optional("4 3")
first Optional("5 4") second Optional("5 4")
first Optional("4 5") second Optional("4 5")
first Optional("3 5") second Optional("3 5")
first Optional("3 4") second Optional("3 4")
first Optional("3 3") second Optional("3 3")
```

You likely want to do the same thing in the next block (the search block):

```
    // Start the search
    while(!otheryQueue.isEmpty){
        let pointPair = otheryQueue.dequeue()
        let button = btnArr[getXFromString(string: (pointPair?.getFirst())!)][getYFromString(string: (pointPair?.getFirst())!)]
        possibleNeighbours = findPossibleNeighbours(btn: button, blockedArr: blockedArr)
        for neighbour in possibleNeighbours{
            if isOnBorder(point: neighbour){
                return (pointPair?.getSecond())!
            }
            
            // add this line
            let pair = Pair()
            
            pair.setPair(firstValue: neighbour, secondValue: (pointPair?.getSecond())!)
            otheryQueue.enqueue(key: pair)
            blockedArr[getXFromString(string: neighbour)][getYFromString(string: neighbour)] = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats it @DonMag! Thank you so much <3 I cannot believe it was because of those 2 lines......